# Output shape of mlmodel NNClassifier is Multiarray, VNClassificationObservation not working?

Tags: swift, xcode, coreml

Need help in deploying coreML model generated from GCP to be built, and deployed on Xcode ?

The app on my iPhone opens up and I can take a picture, but the model gets stuck at 'classifying...'

This was initially due to the input image size (I changed it to 224*224) which I was able to fix using coremltools but looks like for the output I need to have a dictionary output when the .mlmodel that I have has a multiarray(float32) output. Also, GCP coreML provided two files, a label.txt file and .mlmodel.

So, I have two questions:

1. How do I leverage the label.text file during the classification/Xcode build process ?
2. My error happens at

```
     { guard let results = request.results as? [VNClassificationObservation] else {
        fatalError("Model failed to load image")
     }
```

Can I change my mlmodel output from multiarray to dictionary with labels to suit VNClassificationObservation OR VNCoreMLFeatureValueObservation can be used in someway with multiarray output ? I tried it but app on the iphone gets stuck.

Not sure how to use the label file in Xcode. Any help is much appreciated. I have spent a day researching online.

Answer (score 0):

You will only get VNClassificationObservation when the model is a classifier. If you're getting an MLMultiArray as output, then your model is NOT a classifier according to Core ML.

It's possible to change your model into a classifier using coremltools. You need to write a Python script that:

1. loads the mlmodel
2. assigns the layers from `model._spec.neuralNetwork` to `model._spec.neuralNetworkClassifier`
3. adds two outputs, one for the winning class label & one for the dictionary with the probabilities for all class labels
4. fill in the class labels
5. save the mlmodel

Comment: Thanks @Matthijs, this makes sense. I downloaded a GCP built coreML multiclass model and was expecting it to output a classifier model. This is my first time doing this exercise and not sure if it is too much to ask here, but can you help me with some code outline for steps 2,3 & 4. I am guessing I am going to experience this output shape problem even while building a model from scratch on Tensorflow etc.

Comment: It's too much code for me to put here on Stack Overflow. I'll add this specific case as a new chapter in my book (Core ML Survival Guide) because it keeps coming up.